# How to Transition Ephemeral Volumes to Persistent Volume Claims

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, storage, persistent-volumes

Currently, some of my pods are using ephemeral volumes (those created by Docker at the container level). I want some form of persistent data stored in specific directories on the host (like bind mounts in Docker) such that my pods can restart without losing data. Persistent Volume Claims seem to be the best way to do this. How should I go about transitioning my existing pods to use PVCs that copy across data from the existing ephemeral volumes?

Comment: PersistentVolumeClaim and "ephemeral volume" are both Kubernetes-specific terminology.  How are you currently storing the data?  What container technology are you actually using?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Is there any application source code involved, or is this question about managing your deployed application?

Comment: I currently have a deployed application on K8s that is containerized using Docker, and looking to migrate existing Docker volumes to some form of persistent data which is mapped to a specific directory on the host. Importantly, I want to be sure that there is no data from these volumes lost in this transition, and minimize downtime of my containers where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the host, create the directory to hold your data. Eg. `mkdir /local_data`
2. Copy the data to the local directory. Eg. `kubectl cp <namespace>/<pod>:/path/in/the/container /local_data`
3. Check and check again all your data is intact in `/local_data`
4. Create a new pod with the following spec.

Example:

```
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  ...
  nodeName: <name>  # <-- if you have multiple nodes this ensure your pod always run on the host that hold the data
  containers:
  - name: ...
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: local_data
      mountPath: /path/in/the/container
    ...
  volumes:
  - name: local_data
    hostPath: /local_data
    type: Directory
```

Apply and check if your pod runs as expected